# Quiz page enable and disable links on menu

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a website tutorial using php and jquery, that includes lessons and quiz, on the quiz part, the user cannot go to the next quiz or lesson if the previous quizzes are not yet finish. How can I disable the links on my menu so that the user cannot go to the other lessons?

Here is the code for the side menu:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div class="menu-item alpha">
      <h4><a href="#">Menu</a></h4>
      <p>Choose Chapters and Lessons:</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h4><a href="#">Chapter 1</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="les1.php" target="iframe_a">Learning the fundamentals</a></li>
        <li><a href="les2.php" target="iframe_a">Working with JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons/les3.html" target="iframe_a">--------</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h4><a href="#">Chapter 2</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="lessons/les4.html" target="iframe_a">Lesson 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons/les5.html" target="iframe_a">Lesson 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons/les6.html" target="iframe_a">Lesson 6</a></li>
         </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
      <h4><a href="#">Chapter3</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="lessons/les7.php" target="iframe_a">Lesson 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons/les8.php" target="iframe_a">Lesson 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="lessons/les9.php" target="iframe_a">Lesson 9</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Paste the code you have now

Comment: Conditional statements, [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), a dash of jQuery with a Splash of Ajax.

Comment: thanks ,i dont have that much knowledge and idea on jQuery and Ajax cause i only started using it for a month, just for this project. i can imagine the process but i dont know how to execute it in jQuery or ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you just one example of text element one button,

```
if(document.getElementbyId('your_text_input_id').value == '')
     document.getElementbyId('your_button_id').disabled = true;
}
```